# Execute rake task with Open3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to capture output from rake task inside my controller like this:

```
buffer = []
Open3.popen3("rake namespace:task") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  begin
    while line = stdout.readline
      buffer << line
    end
  rescue
  end
end
```

However, the task is never executed. And there is no output. I tried many others commands and everything works fine. Could somebody help me, please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Update 1*

stderr content:

```
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:191:in `rescue in load_spec_files': git://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError)\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:188:in `load_spec_files'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:92:in `local_specs'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:159:in `specs'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n", "\tfrom /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'\n"
```

Comment: Adding `require "open3"` to top of your script and adding `puts buffer` at end of your script works for me.

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi Thanks. Good to know. I'll try to find problem somewhere else.

Comment: You should include error message and stack trace. Sharing controller code would help too.

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi I updated my questions and wrote error message as you suggested. Please take a look.

Comment: I added source 'http://gems.github.com' to the Gemfile and run bundle install. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding source `gems.gthub.com` to the Gemfile solved my problem.